# Add photo to Facebook album of an open group

Tags: image, facebook, upload, facebook-group

Is it possible with php or javascript API adding a picture to a album of a Facebook open group?

I’m able to add picture to my profile with

```
   $data = array(
                "name" => $_POST["message"],
                "image" => "@" . realpath($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]));
            $fb->setFileUploadSupport(true);
            $status = $fb->api("/me/photos", "POST", $data);
```